# JS Date: Add 0 in front of every single day or month

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have this date parsed from an api as a string:
DD-MM-YYYY but sometimes the date is DD-M-YYYY or even D-M-YYYY.

For example:

**4-1-2013**
or
**10-10-2013**
or **7-4-2013**

The year is always 4 digits but days or months sometimes get one digit. **How can I manually (with JS) add 0 in front of a every single digit ?**

I am using moment.js for some calculations thus I am remove the '-' using

```
date.replace("-", "")
```

to get a whole number (eg. 4-1-2013 = 412013) so I can use it with moment.js but if its a single digit, it all gets messed up.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *how* it is getting "messed up"? The Moment.js API supports these formats. If you give it: `moment('4-1-2013', 'D-M-YYYY')` it will interpret that as January 4, 2013.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can normalise your strings first like this:

```
date = date.replace(/\b(\d{1})\b/g, '0$1');
```

which will take any "word" that is just a single digit and prepend a zero.

Note that to globally replace every `-` you must use the regexp version of `.replace` - the string version you've used only replaces the first occurrence, therefore:

```
date = date.replace(/\b(\d{1})\b/g, '0$1').replace(/-/g, '');
```

will do everything you require.

Answer (score 11):

Moment.js supports formats with dashes, so you don't even need to do any string handling.

```
moment('4-1-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY').format("MMDDYYYY");   // 04012013
moment('10-10-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY').format("MMDDYYYY"); // 10102013
```

Answer (score 2):

If the date variable is in a String format(for example from `input[type=date]`) then you need to split the data component into single items.

```
date = date.split('-');
```

then check both the day's and the month's length

```
day = date[0].length==1 ? "0"+date[0] : date[0];
month = date[1].length==1 ? "0"+date[1] : date[1];
```

then get them back together into a format that you desire

```
date = ""+day+month+date[2];
```

Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/dzXPE/

Answer (score 0):

```
var day = new Date();
day = day.getDay();
if(day.toString().length <= 1) {
    day = '0' + day;
}
```

You can use the same for month. I'm not entirely sure you need to convert to string but it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: It would work as the dates I get are strings. You cant define day.getDay(). Imagine 7-4-2013 is a word.